# Drawing multiple arcs using Core Graphics

Tags: core-graphics

I'm trying to draw two concentric circles using Core Graphics. I would expect the following code to draw a blue circle and a smaller white circle inside, however it just draws the blue circle. What am I missing?

```
CGContextRef c = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

CGContextAddArc(c, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2, 100, 0, M_PI * 2, true);
CGContextSetFillColor(c, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]));
CGContextFillPath(c);

CGContextAddArc(c, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2, 90, 0, M_PI * 2, true);
CGContextSetFillColor(c, CGColorGetComponents([[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]));
CGContextFillPath(c);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the fill color in an unnecessarily indirect way. Do this instead:

```
CGContextAddArc(c, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2, 100, 0, M_PI * 2, true);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [[UIColor blueColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillPath(c);

CGContextAddArc(c, self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2, 90, 0, M_PI * 2, true);
CGContextSetFillColorWithColor(c, [[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]);
CGContextFillPath(c);
```

Or, even better, just use UIKit's drawing methods directly:

```
[[UIColor blueColor] setFill];
[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2) radius:100 startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI * 2 clockwise:YES] fill];

[[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
[[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithArcCenter:CGPointMake(self.bounds.size.width/2, self.bounds.size.height/2) radius:90 startAngle:0 endAngle:M_PI * 2 clockwise:YES] fill];
```

Your code is failing because `[[UIColor whiteColor] CGColor]` returns a color in the "gray" colorspace, which has only two components, a "gray" value (0 for black, 1 for white) and an alpha value.  In this case, the context is RGBA, so `CGContextSetFillColor` expects to see 4 components, three for RGB and one for alpha.

[The documentation for `CGContextSetFillColor`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetFillColor) points out:

> Note that the preferred API to use is now
>   CGContextSetFillColorWithColor.

Comment: “the context is RGBA” is a little bit misleading; it doesn't matter so much what color space the context uses for backing, but rather what its [fill color space](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/c/func/CGContextSetFillColorSpace) is. The default isn't mentioned; for a brand-new context, it's probably either RGB or the context's backing color space (which is usually RGB), but setting the fill color with `SetFillColorWithColor`, `SetRGBFillColor`, etc. will set the fill color space as a side effect.

Comment: … So, for example, if you were to `SetFillColorWithColor` a white color, the fill color space would then be a white color space, and `SetFillColor` would expect only one or two components—even if the context's backing is RGB.

Comment: @PeterHosey: Absolutely right, I was oversimplifying for the most common case in an iOS or Mac app. In many years of working with CG, I can't say I've ever had to worry about the fill color space. Maybe I've just been lucky.

Comment: It's come up [a couple](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3743283/30461) of [times before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2383748/drawing-an-offscreen-coloured-square-returns-a-greyscale-image#comment2371544_2388783), but yeah, it's pretty rare.